# Reload pi without NOOBS (e.g. via apt-get)

Tags: noobs, apt

I had a pi running nicely until I rebooted it.  Since then it won't mount cifs drives and I can't think of any other thing to do except start over.  If you can't sleep read [this descent into frustration](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1432393)

Is there a way I can apt-get my way to a pristine install, or do I have to put NOOBS on my SD card and go that way?

Comment: It is unlikely (depends on what you did to stop it running). It is probably futile to suggest restoring from your backup. Don't use `NOOBS` unless you want multiple OS on one card - most of us don't. Just install `Raspbian`.

Comment: This would have been a good moment to celebrate your foresight in keeping current images on your hard drive:  https://www.howtogeek.com/341944/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-foolproof-backup/